# Nlog - MVC - EF - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, nlog

I have installed the latest Nlog and I am getting the subject error.  I have tried 2 different connection strings which point to the same db:
This is an EF MVC application.

```
<add name="Nlog" connectionString="Data Source=NP-DBTRANS01\DEV;Initial Catalog=MainWebsite;Persist Security Info=True;user id=USERID;password=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="MainWebsiteEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MainWebsite.csdl|res://*/Models.MainWebsite.ssdl|res://*/Models.MainWebsite.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=np-dbtrans01\dev;initial catalog=MainWebsite;persist security info=True;user id=USERID;password=PASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I changed the actual userid and pw for obvious reasons.

**NLOG config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="true"
  internalLogLevel="Debug"
  internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <!-- optional, add some variables
  Use these above when not debugging - MK
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Error"
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->

  <!--
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>

    <!--
    add your targets here
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets for possible targets.
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers for the possible layout renderers.
    -->

    <!--
    Write events to a file with the date in the filename.
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    -->
    <target xsi:type="Database" name="dbTarget"
            connectionStringName ="MainWebsiteEntities"
            commandText="INSERT INTO dbo.NLog([TimeStamp], [Level], [Message], [Exception], [User])            
                        VALUES (@timeStamp, @level, @message,  @exception, @user);">
      <parameter name="@TimeStamp" layout="${date}" />      
      <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />     
      <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:format=toString}" />
      <parameter name="@User" layout="${user}" />
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="dbTarget" />
    <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
    -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**I have this in a helper class**
internal static NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

**I call it from my controller like this: (just trying to get something to work)**
Util.Logger.Info("Worked");

I get the subject error in my catch block.  I am sure it is probably something simple.

Thanks in advance
MK

Let me know if i missed anything.

I have tried multiple configs, redoing the Nlog table and then the .edmx file. Updated Nlog

Comment: If using .NET Framework with app.config / web.config then you should use `connectionStringName="Nlog"` instead of `connectionString="Nlog"`. Alternative you could use `connectionString="${appsetting:item=connectionStrings.NLog}"`

Comment: That didn't seem to work .. So I put 
private Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); 
at the top of my controller class and now I get
Exception when parsing C:\Repos\DailyProphet\DailyProphet\NLog.config
I added User to the config and db table.

Comment: {"Exception when parsing C:\\Repos\\DailyProphet\\DailyProphet\\NLog.config.  Updated the Nlog config above.

Comment: The idea is to look at the Exception-details, or the error-messages in the NLog InternalLogger output. Even if you don't understand the meaning, then you should always include the error-details in the question. To me it says `NLog.NLogConfigurationException: 'DatabaseParameterInfo' cannot assign property 'Layout'='${user}'. Error: Failed to parse layout containing type: user - LayoutRenderer type-alias is unknown: 'user'` So you have specified `${user}`, but NLog complains that it doesn't know what it means. Maybe looking for https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-User-Layout-Renderer ?

Comment: Uggg boy do I feel .. yeah not smart.. thanks for pointing the obvious to me .. works now.

Answer (score 0):

The initial error `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0` probably means invalid ConnectionString. Try replacing `connectionString="Nlog"` with:

> `connectionStringName="Nlog"`

The other error `cannot assign property 'Layout'='${user}'. Error: Failed to parse layout containing type: user - LayoutRenderer type-alias is unknown: 'user'` means that NLog doesn't recognize `${user}`. Maybe try using [${environment-user}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-User-Layout-Renderer):

> `<parameter name="@User" layout="${environment-user}" />`